# Z Intersection of Cylinder and Plane Base On Angle Around Cylinder

Tags: geometry, 3d

I'm trying to find the (x, y, z) intersection of a cylinder and a plane given a cylinder aligned to the z axis and a plane rotated around the y axis like that shown below.  The other parameter involved would be the angle around the z axis by which the intersection is located.  This would have the inputs (R, y_rotation, z_rotation) - the cylinder would be centered at (0, 0) and projected to infinity while the plane would also cross through (0, 0, 0).

The (x, y) portion of this is simple enough - it's just projecting a point from the cylinder's center (x, y) by the angle for the distance R - for which I'm using the two formulas below (this is going into OpenSCAD, so the function definitions aren't the prettiest things.)  What I'm stuck on is how to get the Z value of the intersection:

```
function x_cylinder_plane_intersection(z_angle, radius) = (radius * cos(z_angle));
function y_cylinder_plane_intersection(z_angle, radius) = (radius * sin(z_angle));
function z_cylinder_plane_intersection(y_angle, z_angle, radius) = ?
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any point $(x, y, z)$ on the green plane, you have 
$$
\tan \theta = \frac{z}{x}.
$$
hence $z = x \tan(\theta)$.

Letting $t = \tan \theta$, to save a little typing, this means that your third line of code should be something like

```
function z_cylinder_plane_intersection(y_angle, z_angle, radius) = 
            (radius * cos(z_angle)) * tan(theta)
```

Comment: Just to make sure, is `theta` in the function you gave the `y_angle` parameter?

Comment: It looks like `theta` should be `y_angle` per the equation you gave, but this appears to give the wrong answers.  I used `function z_cylinder_plane_intersection(y_angle, z_angle, radius) = (radius * sin(to_radians(z_angle))) * tan(to_radians(y_angle));` but when doing `echo(z_cylinder_plane_intersection(45, 90, sqrt(2)));` I get `0.000531438` where I would expect `+/-1` (not sure of the `+/-` offhand.)

Comment: Correction, removed the radian conversion and I get: `1.41421` or `sqrt(2)` from `z_cylinder_plane_intersection(45, 0, sqrt(2))` - this should come out as `1` unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Marked your answer as correct, sorry for the spam, I was using pythagora's theorem thinking of the distance to the centerpoint instead of the delta z alone.  Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure. I was using $\theta$ to denote...the thing labelled "$\Theta$" in your figure. :)

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that after looking more closely at it, I pulled the image from an image search of something like "plane cylinder intersection" trying to find a diagram suitable to ask with.